# How to animate the Particular Part of the Icon in Vector Drawable?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

Am new to Vector Drawable Animation, in that i have **Notification Active** icon in Vector Drawable.

Notification Icon Vector Path Code:-

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="140dp"
android:height="140dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:pathData="M7.58,4.08L6.15,2.65C3.75,4.48 2.17,7.3 2.03,10.5h2c0.15,-2.65 1.51,-4.97 3.55,-6.42zM19.97,10.5h2c-0.15,-3.2 -1.73,-6.02 -4.12,-7.85l-1.42,1.43c2.02,1.45 3.39,3.77 3.54,6.42zM18,11c0,-3.07 -1.64,-5.64 -4.5,-6.32L13.5,4c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v0.68C7.63,5.36 6,7.92 6,11v5l-2,2v1h16v-1l-2,-2v-5zM12,22c0.14,0 0.27,-0.01 0.4,-0.04 0.65,-0.14 1.18,-0.58 1.44,-1.18 0.1,-0.24 0.15,-0.5 0.15,-0.78h-4c0.01,1.1 0.9,2 2.01,2z" />
```

The Icon Will be Like this

[image]

Want To Animate the Outer Ring only using Vector drawable Animation. Can one Guide me to Learn Vector Drawable animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) paths use the same syntax as [SVG paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html). Following those instructions, you can see that the path traces out the left and right ring parts first, followed by the body and bottom bit.

In order to animate the ringer separately from the body, split it out into its own path.

```
<!-- The ringer -->
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:pathData="M7.58,4.08L6.15,2.65C3.75,4.48 2.17,7.3 2.03,10.5h2c0.15,-2.65 1.51,-4.97 3.55,-6.42zM19.97,10.5h2c-0.15,-3.2 -1.73,-6.02 -4.12,-7.85l-1.42,1.43c2.02,1.45 3.39,3.77 3.54,6.42z" />
<!-- The body -->
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/dark_grey"
    android:pathData="M18,11c0,-3.07 -1.64,-5.64 -4.5,-6.32L13.5,4c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v0.68C7.63,5.36 6,7.92 6,11v5l-2,2v1h16v-1l-2,-2v-5zM12,22c0.14,0 0.27,-0.01 0.4,-0.04 0.65,-0.14 1.18,-0.58 1.44,-1.18 0.1,-0.24 0.15,-0.5 0.15,-0.78h-4c0.01,1.1 0.9,2 2.01,2z" />
```

Then we need to give that part a name so the animator can attach to it, and wrap it in a `<group>` if you want to animate its position or rotation. I eyeballed the pivot point for rotation.

```
<group android:name="ringer" android:pivotX="12" android:pivotY="10.5">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/dark_grey"
        android:pathData="M7.58,4.08L6.15,2.65C3.75,4.48 2.17,7.3 2.03,10.5h2c0.15,-2.65 1.51,-4.97 3.55,-6.42zM19.97,10.5h2c-0.15,-3.2 -1.73,-6.02 -4.12,-7.85l-1.42,1.43c2.02,1.45 3.39,3.77 3.54,6.42z" />
</group>
```

Now you can embed it into an [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) and attach an animation to that group.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector android:width="140dp" android:height="140dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:viewportHeight="24.0">
            <group android:name="ringer" android:pivotX="12" android:pivotY="10.5">
                <path
                    android:fillColor="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:pathData="M7.58,4.08L6.15,2.65C3.75,4.48 2.17,7.3 2.03,10.5h2c0.15,-2.65 1.51,-4.97 3.55,-6.42zM19.97,10.5h2c-0.15,-3.2 -1.73,-6.02 -4.12,-7.85l-1.42,1.43c2.02,1.45 3.39,3.77 3.54,6.42z" />
            </group>
            <path
                android:fillColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:pathData="M18,11c0,-3.07 -1.64,-5.64 -4.5,-6.32L13.5,4c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5s-1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v0.68C7.63,5.36 6,7.92 6,11v5l-2,2v1h16v-1l-2,-2v-5zM12,22c0.14,0 0.27,-0.01 0.4,-0.04 0.65,-0.14 1.18,-0.58 1.44,-1.18 0.1,-0.24 0.15,-0.5 0.15,-0.78h-4c0.01,1.1 0.9,2 2.01,2z" />
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="ringer">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="50"
                android:propertyName="rotation"
                android:valueFrom="-15"
                android:valueTo="15"
                android:repeatCount="infinite"
                android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Don't forget to call [Animatable2#start()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Animatable2.html) on the drawable when you want it to run.

Comment: In XML its show Error Like `Element animated-vector doesn't have required attribute android:drawable`

Comment: @Yugesh The IDE is wrong, it will compile and run fine. If you want to use the IDE, take the `aapt:attr` bits out into separate resource files and write the attributes referencing them. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/complex-xml-resources.html

Comment: Thanks. After complete the animation is Not back to original Position. An XML properties available back to original position or We have set after Animation Completed.